# Flutter Android App crashes when uing google maps

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, plugins, crash

My Flutter App crashes when try to display a google map using the google_maps_flutter package from pub.dev. These are the logs

```
Running with unsound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
I/zzbz    (31588): Making Creator dynamically
D/        (31588): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7f2a9c00, tid 31603
W/zygote  (31588): Unsupported class loader
W/zygote  (31588): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/DynamiteModule(31588): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite:203112999
I/DynamiteModule(31588): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.maps_dynamite, version >= 203112999
V/DynamiteModule(31588): Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
D/        (31588): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x89c0fc00, tid 31625
W/ResourceType(31588): ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 67, previously 69
W/ResourceType(31588): ResTable_typeSpec entry count inconsistent: given 5399, previously 5400
W/zygote  (31588): Unsupported class loader
W/zygote  (31588): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
I/Google Maps Android API(31588): Google Play services client version: 12451000
I/Google Maps Android API(31588): Google Play services package version: 204516022
I/zygote  (31588): Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=24KB
I/zygote  (31588): After code cache collection, code=29KB, data=24KB
I/zygote  (31588): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
W/DynamiteModule(31588): Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
I/DynamiteModule(31588): Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:6
I/DynamiteModule(31588): Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 6
W/zygote  (31588): Unsupported class loader
W/zygote  (31588): Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
Lost connection to device.
```

This is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
   <application
        android:label="myapp"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
         <meta-data 
         android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBx5Lp3oc-aTekzyLykT858a_ECRSEicAU"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
                 Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
                 screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
                 gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
                 Flutter's first frame. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
              android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And i tried using it displaying it like this

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
 
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();



static const LatLng _center = const LatLng(45.521563, -122.677433);
 void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {

_controller.complete(controller);

}



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(

         appBar: AppBar(

           title: Text('Maps Sample App'),

           backgroundColor: Colors.green[700],

           ),

           body: GoogleMap(

             onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,

             initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(

               target: _center,

               zoom: 11.0,

          ),

        ),

      );
  }
}
```

I added `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>` to the AndroidManifest.xml but it still the app still crashes. Can Someone please help me?

Comment: I am using  `google_maps_flutter: ^1.0.6`. Thanks

Comment: Might be related to this https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72185 (?)

Comment: thanks i would check it out

Answer (score 3):

It works if you change the minSdkVersion to 24 in build.gradle.
Could not figure the cause yet.

BTW, it works in java/android studio even if the minSdkVersion is 16.

So it might be a flutter configuration issue.

Comment: I changed my minSdkVersion to 24 and it still crashes

Answer (score 0):

try Gradle version `3.5.0` and min SDK `20`

worked for me